# How to code Auto Mysql 5.5.5 Install for Freebsd shell Script

Tags: mysql, shell, sh, freebsd

Hi everyone i'm trying to code auto mysql 5.5.x install script for freebsd i'm using this code

```
portsnap fetch extract
cd /usr/ports/databases/mysql55-client ; make install clean
cd /usr/ports/databases/mysql55-server ; make install clean
echo 'mysql_enable="YES"' >> /etc/rc.conf
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server onestart
rehash
mysqladmin -uroot password "password"
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server onerestart
mysql -p password
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mt2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mt2!@#' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
flush privileges;
quit
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server onerestart
reboot
```

i've got 2 problems first mysql -p password code is not typing password it asking password again.Second sometimes this screen appears and install stopping.What i have to choose in this screen "ok" or "cancel" and is there a way to pass this screen automaticly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2AAf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do an automated install, use packages instead of ports. As you've seen, in the ports tree you can be asked to choose compile-time options. Packages are built with the default options, so they don't do that.

So to install `mysql`, use:

```
pkg install -y mysql55-server
```

(This will install both the server and client.)

Note the use of the `-y` flag. Otherwise `pkg` will ask for confirmation that you want to install.

Also note that you don't need to have `mysql_enable` in `/etc/rc.conf` to be able start a service *once*. The modern way to start a service once is;

```
service mysql-server onestart
```

According to the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html), if you use the `-p` option you cannot have a space between the option and the password. So you should use `mysql -pYOURPASS` or `mysql --password YOURPASS`.

Additionally, to give input to a command in a shell-script, you should use a [here-document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). Assuming you are using `/bin/sh` in the shell-script;

```
mysql --password YOURPASS << END
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mt2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mt2!@#' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
flush privileges;
quit
END
```

Restarting the mysql server just before a reboot with `onerestart` is not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use a clean freebsd 10+ and and type this command in console :

```
pkg install mysql55-server
```

Add in rc.conf, create thr user and this is it.

Comment: This will still ask for confirmation of the install.